# script variable in tr

Tags: bash, variables, tr

I want to make a script that is looking for special numbers.

numbers like this 153 = 1^3+5^3+3^3

*bash script 153 3*

*153*

In my script I have this kinda thing

```
echo "$1" | tr -d " " | sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)/\1+/g' | tr '+' '^"$2"+'
```

That last command doesn't work, it does change something, it changes `1+5+3+` to `1^+5^+3^+`

So my question is: how can I use variables in tr?

Comment: I think `sed` would be more appropriate here...

Comment: Your first task is to write down what exactly you want to achieve. Forget bash, forget the fact that computers use electrons. Define which input should result in which output. Define it very clear. Then it wil turn out that most of your work is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` replaces one character with another one. It can't replace one character with a longer string. That's `sed`'s job:

```
set -- 153 3
echo "$1" | \
    tr -d " " | \
    sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)/\1^'"$2"'+/g; s/\+$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by choroba is correct. Here is a python based one-liner:

```
$ set -- 153 3
$ python -c "print '+'.join([x+'^$2' for x in list('$1')])"
1^3+5^3+3^3
```

Explanation:

1. list will convert the string `"153"` to `['1', '5', '3']`
2. [ x+'^$2' for x in <list> ]  is called list comprehension. Effectively it returns another list: `['1^3', '5^3', '3^3']`
3. Then join them with `'+'`

NOTE: Only reason I added this answer was because, this does not require to adjust the completed string after processing by build-in functions.

Below are the other common approaches:

```
$ python -c "print '^$2+'.join(list('$1')) + '^$2'" # Add "^3" after join returns "1^3+5^3+3"
$ echo $1 | sed "s/./&^$2+/g; s/+$//" # Remove last '+' sign from "1^3+5^3+3^3+"
```